# Do I need SMTP or POP3 on the server to run PHPMailer?

Tags: phpmailer, sendmail, postfix-mta

I have a busy CentOS webserver that sends a lot of outbound email using PHPMailer. Postfix and Sendmail are both installed on it, but as there are no user accounts that use the server for email, I wonder if I can uninstall both of those and close ports 25,110,465,587 for security. Will PHPMailer still be able to send outgoing?

Answer (score 0):

No, PHPMailer (and any other mail library for any programming language, for that matter) is just an interface for the email service and not a mailer daemon by itself.

You do not need POP (you can shut that down anytime) but you will need sendmail or some other SMTP service to actually do the work PHP Mailer requests.

If you definitely need to shut down sendmail and the related ports, you can always part ways with it and implement your mail delivery logic using Mailgun, SendGrid, Elastic Email, Pepipost or some other alternative. There WILL be coding involved as you'll need to interact with those providers' APIs and they all involve some costs (Mailgun and Sendgrid have free tiers for a couple thousand emails per month, I don't remember if the others do as well) and integration efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be fine to remove any local mail service as PHPMailer is made to use an external service. You can close those ports as it's only outgoing!

> The PHP mail() function usually sends via a local mail server, typically fronted by a sendmail binary on Linux, BSD and OS X platforms, however, Windows usually doesn't include a local mail server; PHPMailer's integrated SMTP implementation allows email sending on Windows platforms without a local mail server.

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you do not *need* to have a local mail server, however, if it's really busy, sending via a local mail server will be far more efficient than sending via any external service, especially if these messages are being sent immediately (and synchronously) in response to HTTP requests. You can see more about this in the PHPMailer wiki on github.

You definitely don't need POP3, but you may need inbound on port 25 if you're going to receive/handle bounces from the messages you send and want them to come back to you.

In this scenario you would only need port 25 open in both directions, none of the others.

Also, be clear what you mean by sendmail. Postfix is a complete mail server and so is [sendmail](https://www.proofpoint.com/us/open-source-email-solution), but the name sendmail is also often used to refer the `sendmail` binary that is actually a local message submission agent - it's what gets used by the PHP `mail()` function. postfix provides a sendmail binary, but postfix is not sendmail.